# Set fancybox title using caption text in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, fancybox

Fancybox has a title attribute that takes in value from the title tag

```
  jQuery.fn.getTitle = function() { 
var arr = jQuery("a.fancybox");
jQuery.each(arr, function() {
    var title = jQuery(this).children("img").attr("title");
    jQuery(this).attr('title',title);
})
```

}

I want to be able to copy the attributes of the caption instead of the title

```
         <dl class="gallery-item">
        <dt class="gallery-icon portrait">
            <a href="***.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="fancybox" title="">
                              <img  src="*****.jpg" alt="item name"></a>
        </dt>
        <dd class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption">
             item name
        </dd>
         </dl>
```

so far I have tried changing the title to

```
          jQuery( this ).children("img").next().text();

                  and 

         jQuery( this ).parent("dt").next().text();
```

but it didn't help. Any other way to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. Got it working like this:

```
$('dl.gallery-item').each(function(){
    var caption = $(this).find('dd.wp-caption-text').text();
    $(this).find('a').attr('title',caption);
    $(this).find('dd.wp-caption-text').remove();    
});
```

Comment: Its been some time since I have posted this question and I solved it already. Forgot how though, anyways I'll put it up as the right answer since I think this is similar to the way it worked for me.